# How to get events for Blazor in C# working?

Tags: c#, html, web, event-handling, blazor

So I'm making a site with blazer in C#. And I'm trying to get it to change text on the screen when someone plays a video... but its not working.

```
@page "/PageSeven"

<p>Play the video</p>

<video @onplay="@onClickPlay" controls width="1280" height="720">
    <source src="/Special.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>

<h1>@fool</h1>

@code   {

    private String fool = "";

    private void onClickPlay() {
    fool = "YOU FOOL!";
}
```

}

Comment: Interesting, this looks like it should have worked.

Answer (score 0):

--edit--

This answer didn't work.  Just leaving it for posterity.

---

Don't return `void` in your handler.  That won't trigger an update.  Use `Task` or `Async Task`

You can probably add `StateHasChanged()` at the end of your method, but I'd recommend changing the signature.

For short commands, you can also use a lambda method:

```
<video @onplay="()=> fool = "YOU FOOL!" controls width="1280" height="720">
```

Comment: No, just `void` is always acceptable in a Blazor event. Give it a spin, I couldn't get any of the the events to fire.

Comment: Okay, I've checked it and the event is not firing at all.  Also, I have an .mp4 file of my own, and it plays only audio, so I don't think a direct stream is guaranteed to work anyway.  I use Azure Media Services for that stuff, but it's not cheap.

Comment: Looks like the Blazor implementation isn't happening yet.  OP will need to use some (pretty basic I guess) JS Interop.

Comment: The event [are handled](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/8b30d862de6c9146f466061d51aa3f1414ee2337/src/Components/Web/src/Web/EventHandlers.cs), I think something broke.

Comment: That's been the case for about a year now.  They said they fixed it, but apparently not. https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/20983  Luckily, it should be pretty easy just to wire up JavaScript Interop for it.